# If $A$ is a square matrix and $k$ is positive, then the set $\{v \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid v^t A v \le k\}$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

At first I thought I could define a norm $||v||=v^tAv$ and then conclude that the set is exactly the closed ball centred at origin with radius $k$. But that function is not a norm since $||v||=0$ does not imply $v=0$.

Later I tried to define a function $f(v)=v^tAv$ and prove that it is continuous (thus the set is the inverse image of the closed set $[0,k]$). However, I don't know how to expand expressions like $v^tAv$ (in order to understand how a sequence $v_n^tAv_n$ converging to $v^tAv$ behaves). I know these expressions are pretty common in linear algebra, but I rarely had to deal with sequences of this kind.

I started with a simple example in two dimensions: if $v=(x,y)$ and $A=(a_{ij})$ then
$$v^tAv=x^2a_{11}+xy(a_{12}+a_{21})+y^2a_{22}$$

Is there a clever way to approach the problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: At first glance your set is $f^{-1}\Big((-\infty,k]\Big)$ where $f(v)=v^TAv$. If you can assume $f$ ia continuous then you're done.

Comment: Yeah, but to prove such a function is continuous I would have to prove that a sequence $v_n^TAv_n$ converges to $v^TAv$. So I would have to expand an expression like: $$||v_n^TAv_n-v^TAv||$$

Comment: You can assume continuity by noting $f$ is a linear combination of monomials. In your example, you were able to express $v^tAv$ as a linear combination of the monomials $x^2,xy,$ and $y^2$ each of which defines a continuous map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Steve You can do it in multiple steps: $v \mapsto Av$ is continuous, $(u, v) \mapsto (u|v)$ is continuous, and composition of continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: Oh, I see... the monomials have the entries of the matrix as coefficients, and the "variables" are the entries of the vector (like the two-dimensional example I wrote)

Thank you very much! Should I leave the question here on the site? Or is there a way to tag answered?

Comment: @Steve You can do an even better approach. Prove the statement for the case that $A$ is a diagonal matrix (easy right, just a sum of weighted squares). For the general case, assume w.l.o.g. that $A$ is symmetric, then use the fact that its eigenvectors are orthonormal, and its eigenvalues real.

Answer (score 1):

mmmm maybe we can try with Lagrange's multipliers? $f(x)=v^tAv$ and $F(x)=v^tAv-K$ and some how show that the maximum reaches when F(x)=0 and is in the set.
for every none symmetric matrix we know that $B=A+A^t$ is symmetric and for symmetric B we know that for $g(v)=<v,Bv>$ we have that $D_g(v) = 2v^tB$...